# Unable to get correct value from a UIAButton

Tags: ios-simulator, ios-ui-automation, appium

While using the Appium Inspector, unable to get correct value from a UIAButton.
I want to get value(i.e. "17:20") from button, but in inspector it shows name of background image in `name` and `label` attribute of button and `value` attribute is null. I am not able to understand why background image name shows in `name` attribute of button. And is there any other way to get this 17:20 value

Please find below screenshot for button and its details. 
[image: Button image]. [image: Details for Button]

Comment: How is the button implemented? How are the accessibility labels set?

Comment: I don't know the implementation of button but accessibility labels are blank.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have selected the correct element?
When clicking at an object with the inspector, it's often selecting objects in the background.
To ensure you have the correct element selected, use the tree selector on the left of the inspector's preview window.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an accessibilityValue to the button, where you initialise the button.

```
self.yourButton.accessibilityValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getYour17:20Valuehere];
```

In Appium you then ask yourButtonElement.getAttribute("value").